# Automatic Review audit - commenting as duplicate leads to fail

Tags: discussion, bug, duplicate-questions, close-reasons, disputed-review-audits

Today I had reviewed as "review audit" following question:

[Changed domain error - OpenId auth request contains an unregistered domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23773275/changed-domain-error-openid-auth-request-contains-an-unregistered-domain)

which ends with

> I have tried Googling that message but apparently I am one of the
>   first four people to see it. Any ideas here?

In order to check if it is true, I have googled by error message "OpenID auth request contains an unregistered domain:" and obviously [found some links](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=OpenID%20auth%20request%20contains%20an%20unregistered%20domain:&oq=OpenID%20auth%20request%20contains%20an%20unregistered%20domain:&aqs=chrome..69i57.276j0j7&client=ubuntu-browser&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8), more precisely - an existed question with answers (see the first link in this question) .

I have tried to add comment about possible duplicate and get a message

```
STOP! Look and Listen.

This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention.
You didn't pass. Your review was inappropriate. 
This was a high quality post and you should have considered leaving it as-is 
or even upvoting.

Don't worry, we've already handled this post appropriately – 
but please take a minute to look it over closely, 
keeping in mind the guidance above.
```

It looks biased for me - I tried not only to review question, but actually check it and help author and community and become 2 days banned for it.

It is right policy?

P.S. Actually it is similar to year ago posted question (see last paragraph), but still actual problem. [Review audits and "I understand" button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188780/review-audits-and-i-understand-button/188790#188790)

UPD.: It is not yet solved problem, one still cannot disagree with audit results. "Don't worry", which is "answer" on provided link IS NOT an answer. Answer would be change in audit, because one still GET BANNED for short time. Is it really "don't worry?"

Comment: So you found some results in Google. So what? Who cares? You just wanted to brag that you're better at searching? We don't need comments like that. It is also not a reason to close the question. You were ***not*** trying to help the author. If so, you'd have done the research and *posted an answer*.

Comment: I have found not "some results", I have found an anwser at SO to the same question. Posting answer to duplicate question is the right policy instead of giving a link to the previous the same question? Then what is use of "it is a possible duplicate" comments?

Comment: Is it a duplicate? If it's a duplicate of a question on Stack Overflow, flag it as a duplicate. "Duplicate" doesn't mean "duplicate of something somewhere on the Internet".

Comment: Review task system instead thought that I had to leave it "as-is" or "upvote" instead - which I have quoted in this question.

Comment: @CodyGray FWIW this use case in review audits is [acknowledged as broken by SE team](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179770/165773 "here"): "it kinda falls apart when you want to close a known-good question as a duplicate.

Fixing this would require dragging in code that's currently being extensively re-written; doing so is not feasible at this time..."

Comment: It is similar, but it is not. If they fixed case you mentioned - they would fix it for CLOSING audit. And I`m not able to suggest close as duplicate for "FIRST QUESTION" audit, I can only comment. So another broken variant.

Comment: @gnat my question is year earlier)

Comment: [question age doesn't matter](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315472/839601)

Comment: @gnat, it was a joke. "Don't worry" IS NOT an answer. Answer would be change in audit, because one still GET BANNED for short time. Is it really "don`t worry?"
real asnwer would be here, btw look at number of support 
 https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188780/review-audits-and-i-understand-button/188790#188790