# Automatic review failed - duplicated answer

Tags: feature-request, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

Today I was doing a *first answer* review, where someone has posted a very first answer. Interested by the topic, I opened the original question to see other answers, and I found that the best answer with 16 upvotes is exactly the same as the answer posted by a new user. I've checked the nicknames and they were different, so that was obvious plagiarism for me and a bad trial of gaining some upvotes, so I flagged the answer as `other (needs moderator attention)` and I wrote about the situation.

After that I have received an information about failing automatic answer, because that was a very good question. I can't agree with that, because that was a duplicated answer of another user.

It's probably the same or similar case as [there](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256727/automatic-review-audit-commenting-as-duplicate-leads-to-fail). The difference is that that user searched this answer on Google, and I have followed the question link and found a duplicated answer. Both those cases looks like incorrect behavior of handling reviewers.

The question is, shouldn't that automatic review tests be changed in some way? Maybe automatic answer tests should create some answer duplicates while having a copied answer (this being reviewed) removed for test purposes? For the time being, inquiring and attentiveness is being punished.

Here is the question contained in this test: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23570589/would-you-ever-write-seq-x-x).

Comment: So when you were looking at that question and thinking "oh my gosh it's plagiarized!" Did you see the second copy of that answer by that user anywhere on that page, or only the original one? It becomes pretty obvious that it's an audit at that point.

Comment: I see only the original one, but isn't it like that answers being not reviewed yet are not visible for others? It is like that all the time when you made a change and wait for approval, no one can see it. The other way is that now you should be aware whether this review is a automatic test or not - if you don't know that such audits exists you have no chance of passing it. And for me that is wrong.

Comment: No. Answers are visible the moment they are posted. They don't go through review first.

Comment: Ok, so it is a different behaviour than a post edits. Anyway, if you don't know about automatic reviews test and you are not suspicious about whether the review task is a test or not, you probably fail the review - which probably is not intended.

Comment: Are you saying that you were presented with this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/4942443 , that you chose to flag it, and that the flagging of this post triggered an audit failure? If so, the problem there seems to be that flagging an upvoted post should not be ab automatic audit failure. I can definitely see reasons for upvoted posts to be flagged in certain situations.

Comment: Yes, I failed after flagging it, with message like "That was excellent answer and you've wrongly chosen to flag it, your bad".

Comment: "if you don't know that such audits exists you have no chance of passing it. And for me that is wrong." <-- The reason I don't like that system. You have to game the system to pass; what kind of test is that? Reviewing is almost completely a subjective process; that's why it's only granted to high rep users. I don't understand how you can have automated tests for that.

Comment: @BradLarson, attempting to make a comment on a good answer/question will also fail you. It's happened to me enough times that now if I want to positively interact with a post while reviewing I will always open the question in a new tab in case it's an audit.