# Can we make rejecting suggested edits easier?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I've been following meta for a while and seen complaints about robo-reviewers accepting invalid edits a few times. After hitting 2k rep I've been on the unpleasant end of the "the edit was already approved" box, too.

Since efforts to suppress robo-reviewerism seem to not stop the behavior, I'm wondering if we could instead make rejecting edits easier so the people who want to reject the edit actually have a fair chance to be "faster"?

When reviewing an "obvious" reject (changed code, changed half the post, etc.) it takes me about a second or two to decide whether to approve or reject the edit but mousing around the interface takes like double that amount until I've selected a reject reason and clicked the submit button. Maybe it's just me being keyboard focused but could we improve the efficiency of the rejection process by adding keyboard shortcuts for the canned rejection reasons (with an option to still open the popup and enter a custom reason) or maybe add a dropdown on the "Reject" button?

I know this won't help in the case when someone alters URLs or changes stuff I have to verify, but by the time I'm done with *those* edits, the time it takes me to do a rollback isn't significant anymore.

Comment: *Or* make the Approve button open a menu similar to the Reject button, and require users to select one or more reasons why they're approving the edit, such as: "This edit fixes formatting, spelling, or grammar issues" or "This edit substantially improves the reader's understanding of the post" etc. [/half-joking]

Comment: Maybe make the system look for edits unanimously rejected then with an AI automatically filter new edits into "maybe" and "looks like the other rejects", with the latter being an *audit*.

Comment: I face this too, so I go to the post and rollback the incorrect approved edit..especially in cases where the edits change valid urls or code blocks to invalid ones.

Comment: Maybe the system could record whether a robo-reviewer reviewed it and allow the Reject to override the vote if so.

Comment: Sometimes I wonder how much the robo reviewers dominate the system; if they mostly do, it's fundamentally broken and this patch won't help much.

Comment: @animuson It is actually a very good idea. Something must be done at least, because the quality of the edit-reviews is getting worse, not better.

Comment: @jpmc26 We need better audits in the Suggested Edits queue. I've seen reviewers who approve everything except audits.

Comment: related: [For gosh sakes, please let me finish my edit reviews!](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254830/for-gosh-sakes-please-let-me-finish-my-edit-reviews) and [Reward slow/careful edit reviews](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252856/reward-slow-carefull-edit-reviews)

Comment: related: [Can we have a system to submit potential robo-reviewers for moderators attention?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223947/can-we-have-a-system-to-submit-potential-robo-reviewers-for-moderators-attention)

Comment: What might be more useful is that after being approved, the edit can hang around in limbo for as long as someone has it in his review queue (minus a timeout) and when there an edit gets rejected, it gets thrown into review again. So instead of "already approved" you would get "lets do it all again"

Comment: @S.L.Barth I think audits are fundamentally broken. See here for one reason why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256761/automatic-review-failed-duplicated-answer#comment31822_256761.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Don't allow suggested edits to be "finished" while someone has clicked "improve"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260341/dont-allow-suggested-edits-to-be-finished-while-someone-has-clicked-improve)

Comment: Related: [Can we make approving suggested edits harder?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/292368)

Answer (score 73):

Some suggestions:

- Whenever someone is reviewing an edit, then they should have exclusive access to it. Do not allow people to review the same post in parallel. Instead, lock the reviewed post for other reviews for a certain amount of time (15 minutes?)
- Give reject votes more weight than accept votes. Very few robo-reviewers use reject. In general, a reject usually means that you've taken some time to review the edit.
- For users with high enough rep, add a roll-back button. When you see an obviously incorrect edit, reject it and get hit by "already approved", you need to rollback the edit. When this button is pressed, the high rep user should type in the reason for the rollback. Then the edit should not only be reverted, but the editor and the robo-reviewers should get notified of this, so they stop doing the same mistake.

Comment: I like the [**"lock"**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) and really like the **`roll-back` button** on the spot as even myself I often go back to the post and roll-back an edit if it was incorrect.

Comment: Locking for all forms of reviewing would be very helpful, and frankly I don't see why it hasn't been implemented yet. Reviewers want to get review, and they feel they have to do it fast before other people do it for them. Locking would let the reviewers look over the post carefully and make a sensible decison

Comment: The locking makes a lot of sense. Reviewing should not be a race, everybody should be able to take as much time as he needs. And the rollback button would also be a great improvement. I think it is a good idea to notify the user that an edit they approved has been rolled back and this can also be combined with automatic review bans when too many approved edits are rolled back. If the notification would indicate to the reviewers that they are close to a review ban it would certainly discourage this behaviour.

Comment: And the other hand, could we get a "Do Approve" button to accept rejected edits ? I've been notified a couple times of edits on my answers that were rejected, but I (author of the answer) could not accept them... so I had to type them in.

Comment: It seems to make more sense to allow multiple users to have the lock at the same time. Allowing maybe the number of users equal to half the number of votes required to reject or accept an edit would seem logical. Additionally, a timeout on the lock also seems necessary, maybe something like 20 or 30 minutes, to avoid a review getting "deadlocked."

Comment: +1 for most of the stuff, but not so sure about locking.

Comment: The problem I have with locking is my gut feeling about the amount of rubber-stampers: if they drown out more careful reviewers, we won't even get a dissenting voice on the suggested edit. Maybe if we combine this with tallying (ie, require a **total** of three positive reviews to approve it) it might help. +1 for the roll-back button.

Comment: I think 15 minutes is way overkill.  How long does it really take to review a change?  Lets think about something closer to 2 minutes.

Comment: The problem with locking is that it would slow down all reviewing, including ones which could substantially help answers, in turn slowing down the response and activity rate (some people will leave if they can't read the question that well) of questions that are geniunely great but need a bit of editing since, for example, they were written by someone with bad English skills.

Comment: As for locking: rather than truly locking it, maybe even just not listing it for a minute or until the reviewer decided suffices?

Comment: @Sammaye Today, each edit must be reviewed by 5 people, so that's 6 people involved just to make it go through. So I very much doubt "edit speed" is a major concern. Also, high-rep users can still instantly edit posts without the edit going through the review queue.

Comment: @Lundin well consider it now taking 90 mins to approve a post if not originating from a high rep user

Comment: @Sammaye - How will it slow it down? It should speed it up. If someone is reviewing an edit it would be locked, and out of the queue. The next reviewer will have the next edit to review and then everyone is productive. If I am reviewing an edit, and I click to approve/reject (whatever) and I am told it has already been approved, my time has been "wasted" in that the system is preventing me from being productive. This happens many times to many people and each time the efforts are duplicated like this, it is one more edit that is left in the queue that could have been reviewed.

Comment: TBH I cannot really remember what I said here

Comment: Just to be clear, when we're talking about "Robo reviewers", are we talking about 1) a user who is employing a script that automates the review/approve process 2) an official "StackExchange" process that automatically processes reviews based on particular criteria, or 3) a user who just quickly, without possibly taking the time to do a proper review, simply does: click-review click-approve, click-review click-approve ... over and over again?

Comment: @Sammaye - Sorry. I was talking about the comment you made 6 or 7 comments up, that starts: "The problem with locking is that it would slow down all reviewing ...".

Comment: "_When this button is pressed, the high rep user should type in the reason for the rollback_" Or simply have the same dialog as the Reject dialog, allowing the user to choose between options for why he wants to rollback.

Answer (score 11):

The only thing that I can think of at the moment that *might* help could be to make approval a more complicated procedure.

Currently approving an edit takes one single click, whereas rejecting it takes three (select the "reject" button to bring up the dialog, select the reason and finally close the dialog).

If (and this is a big "if") we made the accept option take three (or even four clicks) then this *might* have the following effect:

1. Some people will give up reviewing suggested edits as it has now become "too complicated".
2. People rejecting edits are now more likely to be able to get their votes in.
3. Some people might actually start thinking about the edits a little more.

I've no idea what those steps could be - they need to be meaningful and add value otherwise most people will abandon reviewing suggested edits altogether.

However, all this is conjecture and might actually do nothing to stop the robo-reviewers.

Comment: @gnat - OK. I should have added "that I can think of"

Comment: @gnat: That's a good idea. Ticketmaster does that when buying tickets. It only lets you hold them a certain amount of time (about 10 minutes). It has the effect of sort of forcing you to hurry up and buy but it also gives everyone else a crack at the seats.

Comment: On top of this, the edit has to have a certain number of positive reviews citing the same reason. Robo-reviewers are likely to choose one at random (or the first one). This will not help when an edit touches several things (readability, format, tags...).

Comment: I posted a suggestion based on this idea (making approval similarly "complicated" as rejection) here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/292368/1025391

Answer (score 4):

I don't think a tiny bit of speed will make a difference. Even if you get your reject vote in on time, it'll still almost certainly get robo-approved it it would have been approved before. Then it'll just not be unanimous. Relevant anecdote: The other day, I got overruled on an edit whose comment was literally "minor edits", which just fixed a couple of lowercase "I"'s. As long as the vast majority of voters will accept literally any edit, even ones that openly state they should be rejected, it doesn't matter whether they do it before or after you vote to reject.

Comment: It's just anecdotal evidence, but I've had it happen several times that I was the last missing rejector (ie, two others had already rejected and got overruled). Need to back up this with hard data, tho.

Answer (score 4):

Given the speed with which the edit review queue clears out and the problems we're discussing, it seems prudent to increase the number of votes required to accept/reject an edit.

Comment: Simply increasing the number of votes will not help. The number of (robo-)approvers is bigger then the number of things to approve and greatly bigger that the number of approvers how actually spend some time before clicking "approve" or "reject". Using different weights for approve and reject votes could help, but it is grey territory that could greatly impact the balance into "everything will be rejected" side.

Answer (score 3):

Speeding up the reject route seems the wrong approach. Reviewers need time to make a considered judgement for suggested edits. Slowing down the accept route seems better. There is a timer on writing comments on Q&As, could something similar be done for reviews?

Perhaps for reviewers with under some reputation points (2000 or 3000 perhaps) an edit accept or reject would only be accepted 30 seconds after the system has displayed it. (Clicking too early could restart the timer.) That would force users to have the post on screen for longer.

Comment: Why restrict it based on rep? At worst, this would bother a careful review on only the very simplest of edits that required no more than a glance, and I suspect they would appreciate the effect on robo-reviewers enough not to be upset about it. It would only really be a problem for people who habitually just accept edits. Of course, this wouldn't solve the problem completely, but I think it could only improve the situation.