# I don't agree with an Audit.

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

While on the first-post review queue, I flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29457319/what-is-the-reason-behind-having-only-one-return-value-in-c-and-java) question as a duplicate - and got admonished for failing an audit. **You didn't pass.**, it said.

Looking at this question in the absence of it's answers, score and active current discussion, it absolutely is a duplicate - asked, discussed and answered several times on SO already.

If put in the same situation again, I feel like I would apply the same flag again. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then go to the question itself and flag it for closure.  If it ends up getting even one vote to close, it will be ineligible as an audit going forward.

Comment: @RaGe ["FWIW this use case in review audits is acknowledged as broken by SE team"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256727/automatic-review-audit-commenting-as-duplicate-leads-to-fail#comment31386_256727)