# A verbatim duplicate of a very old question

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, dupehammer

I dupehammered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37735579/315052) (which has now been deleted), and was surprised to see that it was actually copied verbatim from the original question, asked three years earlier.

Is there anything more I should do other than marking the question as a duplicate?

Comment: I noticed [this meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/304100/315052), but it is not really related to my question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given the verbatim copy and completely worthless suggested edit, I'd guess this is a spammer or troll trying to get past new-user restrictions somehow.

So... Downvoting would be a good thing to do too.

Beyond that, if you want to flag and note your observations, a moderator might wish to preemptively destroy the user. This is optional though, and you might skip it in cases where the account has no other suspicious activity.

Comment: Yes, I am unaware of all the tools at the disposal of moderators. I wasn't sure if moderators had a way to place users on a "watchlist" for future similar infractions, or if bad behavior was picked up automatically by some machine learning mechanism and so flagging for moderator attention is not necessary.

Comment: Also impersonating an SE employee, unless [Tom Limoncelli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/71978/tomontime?tab=profile) has a doppelgänger.