# Failed audit - but question is answered by another

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

Looking at [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/15720894), I decided that the question was well-written and asked, but that it was answered by [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17234543/1896169), so I voted to close it as a duplicate.

Should well-written questions be left open even if they are answered by another? Is this not what it means to be a duplicate?

Comment: Yeah, if you find a dupe, the audit is guaranteed to be wrong. There's not a lot that can be done about this; just go back and vote to close it outside the queue and hopefully that particular candidate will be removed soon enough by dupe-closure.

Comment: My sympathies since I encountered one of these as well. Is the standard procedure to close this meta question as a duplicate of [this canonical meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/304100/review-audit-failed-mark-as-duplicate-is-inappropriate-even-though-it-is-a)?