# Review Audit tagged as "opinion based", while it was a dupe

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

the review was: https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/20516063

Q: [Android Plugin for Gradle 3.0.0 : Could not find com.google.http-client:google-http-client-parent:1.24.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51623523/android-plugin-for-gradle-3-0-0-could-not-find-com-google-http-clientgoogle-h)

and I wanted to comment (and already was noticed, that it is an audit):

> Possible duplicate of 
>   [Gradle sync failed: Could not find com.google.http-client:google-http-client-parent:1.24.1. Searched in the following locations:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51628413/gradle-sync-failed-could-not-find-com-google-http-clientgoogle-http-client-par)

and leave the question closed, because it was a duplicate (which was closed, because it was "opinion based", while it wasn't really opinion-based).

and then ...

> STOP! Look and Listen.
>   This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. You didn't pass. There are no major problems with this question. You should click Reopen, or make minor corrections via Edit and Reopen.
>
> Don't worry, we've already handled this post appropriately – but please take a minute to look it over closely, keeping in mind the guidance above.

the point is, that I did pay attention and found the duplicate, just could not comment there.

now I've voted to close the other quite recent [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51628413/gradle-sync-failed-could-not-find-com-google-http-clientgoogle-http-client-par), for being the actual dupe.

Comment: Review audits are selected automatically, so you're bound to have some bad ones. The best you can do in this case is go through to the question and vtc it to punt it into the close vote queue and remove it as a known good audit.

Comment: basically, one could attempt to comment on every review and then click `skip`, to get around those audits. if the commenting would also be simulated, one wouldn't realize the audit.

Comment: Audits aren't meant to be extremely sneaky, they're meant to filter out people who don't care at all and just click whatever to get the badges. There are many ways you can find out if something is an audit.

Comment: @gnat I've clicked `leave closed`, it rather collided with a recent question, which was about a week old.

Comment: oh, this seems to be a [known bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/304100/839601) then