# Why do I fail a review audit for correctly marking a question as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, disputed-review-audits

So here I was, happily reviewing some first posts to start my Monday morning, when a question titled [Why doesn't “margin: auto” center an element vertically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34552116/why-doesnt-margin-auto-center-an-element-vertically) comes across my queue. I think to myself, "well, this is a well formatted and posed question, but there must be an answer to it already".

So as a resourceful SO user, I go to the googles, and type in "why doesn't margin auto align vertically". The first result is another SO question, this one titled [Using margin:auto to vertically align div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12415661/using-marginauto-to-vertically-align-div) (the second result was the question in question, but we won't make this about my lack of observational skills).

"Aha!", I exclaim. "This has an excellent answer, well sourced and very detailed, I'll flag the review question as a duplicate, and the user will be able to see the link to the other question and find him/herself an answer".

I happily copy/paste the link to the duplicate question into the dupe box, and BAM! I get the "STOP! Look and Listen." dialogue.

<s>What I'm trying to say is that we shouldn't be using questions like this, regardless of how well written they are, for review. I feel like this is a question that anyone with a little html/css knowledge will know has been asked before, and they'll review it with a process similar to the one I just described.</s>

The above paragraph is no longer relevant because I now know that review audit questions are picked by an algorithm. I guess the new request is that we somehow change the behavior when you correctly mark the question in the review audit as a duplicate.

Comment: I would argue that the answers on [the question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34552116/) in question are better and more detailed (namely BoltClock's) than the ones provided in the duplicate you linked to (although I may be biased since I [posted an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34552277/2680216) on that question). But nonetheless, I think you did the right thing. The audit system just has no way of knowing whether a good audit is a duplicate question.

Comment: This is clearly a duplicate of a question asked 3 years ago - the one you found as the first Google result. Oddly, no one raised a flag on it, and due to having no close votes and being highly voted it was picked for audit.

Comment: But it's not marked as a duplicate, how would you expect the audit selecting bot to know that it is one? Are you aware that review audits are not manually selected?

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan The system doesn't need to automatically detect duplicates, but as suggested in a comment of a now deleted answer: the system doesn't need to fail the audit for such flags either, since this flag doesn't necessarily mean that you did something wrong. "Bill the Lizard" (the author of the deleted answer) mentioned that this can be misused by robo reviewers, but this can be handled, I guess. Maybe the original author of this comment will create a feature request.

Comment: @Tom Well that's a fair point, I think that would make sense as a question suggestion. OP's current title asks the opposite *"Why are we using questions that have duplicates in review audits?"*, so if they want to instead ask about not being failed for marking duplicates then they ought to reword it.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan you are absolutely correct, and I will reword the question title. I posted this before I had a good understanding of how the system picked these questions for review audits but through some (now deleted) answers and comments I understand it far better.

Comment: [they can't fix that bug since May 2013](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256727/automatic-review-audit-commenting-as-duplicate-leads-to-fail#comment31386_256727)

Comment: @gnat it's not quite the same. The question you linked looks like it was someone trying to comment on the question and say "Hey, check out this one, it might help you" rather than flagging but with the same result. However, that could just be the OP not being a native English speaker (which, judging by some of the grammar in his post he is not).

Comment: @gnat also after some digging, I did find [this post on review audits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179651/close-vote-review-audit-flawed-fails-without-casting-vote) but again, it's not quite the same thing and has been fixed I believe.

Comment: Sounds to me like the review audit process should give a pass to a response of "Closed as Duplicate" - but should be smart enough to issue another review shortly, and if too many (3 in a row?) are "Closed as Duplicate" something similar to the "Stop - Look - Listen" dialog should come up.

Answer (score -24):

A review audit isn't the final judgement on your worth as a person. Failing one does not mean that you will have your car impounded, be denied entrance to heaven, or be broken up into smaller, less systemically important banks.

It is simply a basic check which stops people from doing a certain type of annoying and counter-productive behavior. If you aren't doing this behavior then **relax**. You have been warned by mistake. Unfortunately it is easier and more practicable to give you the unnecessary warning than to make all review audits perfectly sensible, or to allow robo-reviewers to slip through. You are the unfortunate 'victim' of this.

**It doesn't matter.**

Comment: If the warning is by mistake, then surely the appropriate people should be notified?

Comment: I think that OP is pointing out a legitimate problem, we can discuss the feasibility of fixing it, but "relax" is an incredibly dismissive answer.

Comment: **It doesn't matter** is also not strictly correct. Audits have a real effect, and bad audits should be dealt with.

Comment: @HugoZink Why? To what benefit?

Comment: @jwg so they can fix it, and thus improve the user experience (and prevent incorrect and unjustified review timeouts).

Comment: @HugoZink This is a circular argument. If you don't agree that mistaken review fails are a big deal, there is no need to 'fix' all of these errors.

Comment: @jwg but they are a big deal, since failing too many audits can prevent you from reviewing for some time.