# Old question marked as duplicate of a new question

Tags: discussion, support, duplicate-questions

This question: [Does Java's foreach loop preserve order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35010846/does-javas-foreach-loop-preserve-order), was asked today.

Then i saw that another question which is 6 years old and has several upvotes and good answers was marked as a duplicate of the new question: [Java For-Each Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376934/java-for-each-loop-sort-order).

My questions here are:

- Shouldn't it be the other way round? (The new question marked as duplicate of the old)
- What can one do about that? Maybe write a flag "in need of moderator intervention"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I closed the old one as a duplicate of the new one because:

- the questions are of comparable quality
- the [most upvoted answer to the newer question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35011052/829571) is more detailed, backed by official references (language specification) and therefore seems better to me

I found the old one while looking for a duplicate for the new one but I could not find a duplicate that had answers of similar quality as [Tunaki's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35011052/829571), hence my decision.

Comment: @assylias - I believe this is still unfair to the asker of the original question. All the attention will now be redirected to the new question which will keep earning reputation points, while the original question won't.

Comment: @Matteo I don't think fairness is relevant here. I think I've made the best Q&A is more prominent, which the only thing that really matters. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252930/829571: "*Age doesn't matter here*".

Comment: @assylias - Thanks for the prompt reply and great pointers. It seems that the whole argument is still considered very subjective (as another moderator might have chosen differently)... But I guess that's just how it's gonna be.

Comment: Many do this to "play the points game" and take an old question and then mark it as duplicate when the newer poster should have actually searched to see if the question was already asked...  They can gain points from the duplicate redirection...  I've even seen the person marking the duplicate as the person who answered the newer question and is gaining the credit from bundling up older answers... Kinda sad but it's been happening for a while...

Comment: @KevinCook, it seems to me that the appropriate course of action in such a situation would be to either flag the user for moderator attention or to seek recourse with the Stack Exchange team per https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/28867/372714. It's better to handle the particular instance of abuse rather than risk introducing suspicion into the process of duplicate enforcement. I've noticed you've mentioned this before. If you think it's a broader issue, I suggest you raise it here on the Meta if it hasn't been discussed already.

Comment: If this is acceptable, then the sentence "This question has been asked BEFORE and already has an answer." should be changed.

Comment: This is against the culture which we encourage users to research first before asking in our community.  Besides good answers, the community should also value good and original questions. It’s not about points, but about the culture here in SO. That’s why I’m against this answer and downvoted.